# Why electron's window is not hiding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm new to electron, I created a window using `BrowerWindow` in electron app, and I set `show: false` in the constructor, But the window still appears when I executes the app. Please help me.

Electron version  - **^12.0.2**

```js
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  ipcMain,
  Menu
} = require('electron');

const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

app.whenReady().then(() => {  
  createMainWindow();

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createMainWindow();
    }
  })
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

let mainWin;
function createMainWindow() {
  mainWin = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: false,   
    show: false, 
    icon: path.join(__dirname, '../src/assets/icons/png/64x64.png'),
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,  
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  });

  mainWin.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, '../renderers/index.html'));
  mainWin.maximize();
}
```

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-ready-to-show

Comment: FWIW: I figured this out by looking at the `show` prop docs. Immediately below the `show` prop is some verbiage that led me to think there's more going on than is obvious--the `paintWhenInitiallyHidden` docs led me to the `ready-to-show` event docs, which explains what's happening.

Comment: @DaveNewton, Thanks for the response, I went through the docs but I couldn't figure out that how can I hide a window completely. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `maximize()`.

See [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winmaximize):

> Maximizes the window. This will also show (but not focus) the window if it isn't being displayed already.

I guess I'm not sure what the best way of solving this is. Would it work to just call `hide()` after maximizing the window?

That being said, if you don't want the window to be visible, why even maximize it?